# Facebook Query Of Friends and Common Places

Tags: android, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I am working on an android app that interacts with facebook places.I have the users place list(checkins,status) and the users's friends list.I also have the place list for each of the user's friends.I would like if its possible to query facebook for the common places that the user has with each of his friends.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: Do you have access to the users' friends list?

Comment: Yes I have access to the users friend list and to the friends checkins history

Answer (score 1):

I just found this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

With Checkin you can query the where a user and a place interact.

I found this problem before (one year ago), but I was crawling posts and comments. These posts and comments have the `place` parameter (see this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)), so you can take the last one associated to the user to be the current location or so.

Comment: but if you have the user's place and his friend's places, what else do you need? you can match them

Comment: I can use this query[SELECT,target_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid = me() )] for user checkins and this query[SELECT author_uid,target_id, FROM checkin WHERE (author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())) LIMIT "whatever"] for user friends checkins and handle the responses in android.But I was wondering if i can avoid this procedure and use a single FQL query

Comment: Maybe you should ask that, it is a a simpler question.